# How to stay in the same login with SAP Connection?

Tags: authentication, session, sap-gui

I am trying to automate some SAP Data reports, I am using Visual Basic 2017 and SAP Logon 750, all works fine so far but if there's an open connection then a pop up shows with message:

> **User XXXXX is already logged on**
>
> [image: SAP Logon SAP GUI User is already logged on]

How can I choose radio button and click either on Confirm Button or Cancel button?

I want to click on the check or  button and continue with the same logon.

How can I accomplish that?

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Get_Btn.Click
        Dim application As Object
        Dim SapGui As Object
        Dim connection As Object
        Dim session As Object

        '=================Check Open Sessions==================

        '===Activate SAP logon pad engine

        application = CreateObject("Sapgui.ScriptingCtrl.1")

        '===Initiate one of the predefined SAPlogon pad connection

        SapGui = GetObject("SAPGUI")

        application = SapGui.GetScriptingEngine

        connection = application.OpenConnection("LA TEST", True)

        session = connection.children(0)

        Try
            session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
            session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").text = "zc98"
            session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey(0)

        Catch ex As Exception

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can activate the script recording before logging on to SAP. Then you can see which commands are used. In my test example I recognized the following:

```
...
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/radMULTI_LOGON_OPT1").select
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
...
```

Regards, ScriptMan

Comment: You may need to identify if you are on the "multiple logon" screen. You can do that by checking `session.Info.Transaction` and `session.Info.ScreenNumber` (or something like that) - We have observed that the transaction seems to be 'S000', or '/SAPAPO/SAPAPO' (for APO systems) and the screen number 500.